# Creating an KVM Virtual Network

Tags: networking, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, virt-manager

I'm new to Ubuntu and I'm a bit confused. I wanted to create a virtual network for one of my virtual machines, so I opened virt-manager and went to edit -> Connection Detail and stopped the default and created a new virtual network. Now my vm wont boot, and I get this error message.

```
"Error starting domain: Requested operation is not valid: network 'default' is not active"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 89, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 125, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 82, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1508, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1062, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: Requested operation is not valid: network 'default' is not active
```

Does anyone know why I can't create a virtual network for this vm and disable/delete the default?

Comment: Consider to write your solution as answer to help others and/or yourself in the future :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you disable or delete a virtual network, then virtual machines which were using that network cannot start. You can edit the virtual network card for each guest that was using a disabled or deleted virtual network, and change it to a virtual network that is active and enabled. You can then start that guest.

Answer (score 0):

There was a setting in the show virtual hardware details that allowed me to change from the default network to the network I wanted under the NIC.